# New laravel project without authentication

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and it is baffling me that it just assumes I want a full authentication stack built in every time I create a new project. Is there a way to generate a new project without it adding all of these authentication controllers, classes, etc?

[image]

Comment: No. But it does not represent a problem. Just delete those files or don't use them. They're just there but Laravel does not force you to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These classes aren't used at all unless you run `php artisan make:auth`. If you don't want authentication, you're free to safely remove them.

As of Laravel 5.8, there is no way to generate a project without these files.

Comment: seems crazy to me. thanks for the info though I appreciate it